# Strange codeigniter issue

Tags: codeigniter

When I upload my fully working codeigniter app on live server it did not find any controller and cotroller action.

For example:

my local url is:

```
localhost/myapp/index.php/testcontroller/testaction
```

Yes, It works fine, But when I upload the same thing and url becomes:

```
livesite.com/index.php/testcontroller/testaction
```

It does not work. Shows error that cant fine the controller. I am wondering why it is happening so while it is working on local server. 
Kindly help

controller code:

```
<?php
class Ajaxification extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();$this->load->model('MAjaxification');
    }
    public function Index(){

    }
    public function getUserDetail(){
        $this->load->model('MAjaxification');
        $uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
        echo $this->MAjaxification->getUserdetail($uid);
       // echo "A test response";
    }
    public function getRandomUser(){
       $top = $_REQUEST['top'];
       $left = $_REQUEST['lef'];
      // $this->load->model('MAjaxification');
     //  print_r($this->MAjaxification->getRandomDonoers());*/
        $this->db->select("users.sno,users.full_name,users.userid,users.email,users.pic");
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('donors','users.userid=donors.userid');
        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $this->db->limit(51);
        $res= $this->db->get();

        foreach ($res->result() as $row)
        {
          ?> <div style="border:0px solid black; width: 31px; height: 29px; float: left;">
        <a onclick="getUserinfoDetail('<?=$row->userid?>')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img width="40" height="40" src="../profile_pix/<?=$row->pic; ?>" /></a>
    </div><?php
        }

    }

    private function countUsers(){
        $this->db->select("users.sno,users.pic");
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('donors','users.userid=donors.userid');
        $res = $this->db->get();
        return $res->num_rows();
    }
    function getRandUser($f=1,$t){
       $index = rand($f, $t);
       return $index;
    }
    public function testme(){
        echo "This is a test";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with link to site? It might be misconfigured install or are you sure you have uploaded all files?

Comment: http://dustyfeet.designers99.com/index.php/ajaxification/testme
You can see that http://dustyfeet.designers99.com is working

my base_url is:
$config['base_url'] = 'http://dustyfeet.designers99.com/';

Comment: Other Controllers looks like work, are you sure there is this controller? Please paste the code of that controller please?

Comment: Yes, it is working on my local server

Comment: All controller code is not possible in this comment

Comment: It's hard to say wats wrong if I can't see the code.

Comment: See controller code in the post. I have edited

Comment: Yes checked with case, still the same error

Comment: Is filename of this Application/Controllers/ajaxification.php

Comment: `$this->load->model('MAjaxification');` will not be the mistake, but why are you loading this in constructor and in function?

Comment: [link](http://dustyfeet.designers99.com/index.php/Ajaxification) This works, so somethings wrong with case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with Codeigniter, but if it is similar to Kohana, you have to setup the base_url.
[EDIT]
Check this post from CodeIgniter forum: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Automatic-configbase-url

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem may be related to some configs in application config folder
routes.php :

- $route['default_controller'] you should be set it to the default controller

  config.php :
- $config['base_url'] should be '' if you used the htaccess rules to remove index.php in the URL
  and also the .htaccess file in the app directory may be causing this problem

Also the controller filename must be the same name of the class which extends the CI_Controller

Answer (score 1):

In config.php add base_url like this; this will automatically get URL:

$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $base;

Comment: wow.... this was asked 9 years ago when I was a kid.

Comment: @Shahid Karimi Some posts age like wine. ;-)